# Which one is better "had broken down" or "had been broken down"?

Tags: passive-voice, past-perfect, active-vs-passive

I want to know which of these two sentences below is correct both grammar and meaning wise :

> So many appliances in our apartment **had been broken down** and then got repaired

OR

> So many appliances in our apartment **had broken down** and then got repaired

I prefer the first sentence because passive grammar is used in it , and I should say that I have an IELTS exam in less than a month and I want my mistakes to be corrected , if here is not the right place for asking such questions , let me know please.

Thanks.

Comment: You'd only use ***had been broken down*** if you meant the appliances were ***dismantled*** (perhaps in order to recycle various components).

Comment: @FumbleFingers it does work if you add a timeframe, e.g. "the appliances had been broken down **for a long time** before we bothered fixing them."

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If an appliance *breaks down*, it stops working. If it *is broken down*, someone takes it apart deliberately.

Presumably the appliances in the apartment *had broken down* rather than *had been broken down.*

Comment: your conclusion is right but your first sentence isn't true if you think about it, for example 'sorry I can't drive tonight as my car is/has broken down' is perfectly fine common parlance and doesn't imply someone has dismantled my car :)

Comment: @jdk Kate's first sentence is perfectly true.  In most dialects, _my car is broken down_ is NOT the same as _my car has broken down_; although your particular dialect may be different.

Comment: @jdk - Yes, but you wouldn't say _My car has been broken down_. I was referring to _be broken down_ as a passive verb rather than _broken down_ as an adjectival phrase.

Comment: @kate bunting - "Yes, but you wouldn't say My car has been broken down." Really? what's wrong with 'my car's been broken down since last wednesday'?

Comment: @dawood - "my car is broken down is NOT the same as my car has broken down" -  I didn't say they were the same, I said either is a perfectly fine sentence.  Kate's exqmple is definitely wrong and that ought to be clear to any native English speaker. Perhaps you are confused by the is/has part. An English speaker would not usually pronounce it, and it would usually be written as 'my car's broken down', leaving the details of the contraction  (whether it is an is or a has) unexplained. No English speaker could object 'to my car's broken down' as a perfectly good sentence.

Comment: @jdk - Well, you admit in your own answer that _had been broken down_ is, at the least, ambiguous!

Comment: @KateBunting Who told you what "If it is broken down, someone takes it apart deliberately" might mean?

That does apply in many circumstances and equally clearly, it does not apply in others.

Comment: Sorry @jdk, based both on this, and on other answers of Kate's that I've read, I'm pretty sure she is a native speaker, and her answer is correct.  Maybe you and she speak different dialects; that's fine.  But as for her first sentence - _"... if an appliance breaks down it stops working ..."_ - what on earth would make you think this isn't true?  I am curious to know which dialect of English you speak, because I've never encountered a dialect in which appliances continue to work after they break down.

Answer (score 5):

Please note:

ACTIVE usage:
Appliances often **break down** after a few years.
The car broke down on the highway.

VERB: to break down, to no longer work or be functional.

PASSIVE VERB: to break down, to take apart

The industrial machines **were broken down** for parts and then sold.

Answer (score 0):

**"Had been broken down [by something]"** is the implication of "Had been broken down".

**"Had broken down"** doesn't have that implication.

Answer (score 0):

"Had been broken down"(past perfect continuous*)refers to what was in the past and raises ones curiosity as to whether it is still broken down. "Had broken down"(past perfect*)leads one to think that it is probably still broken down.
I hope this makes sense and is helpful to you. If I had more information I could give a response that is more closely tailored to your needs.
ref:*my own high school teachers many years ago! :)
To answer your question-It depends on the context of what you are writing about as to which one is correct.
Okay, It's the 2nd one that is correct!! Take care now!

Comment: Hi Joanna, welcome to ELL! A note: this is about 'broken *down*', specifically. In case you haven't, I suggest always reading through the existing answers.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I hope I managed to alleviate what's missing from what you've suggested.

Answer (score -1):

'had broken down and then got repaired' is the clearer way to say it. As the answers from other posters implied, 'had been broken down' is ambiguous. It doesn't necessarily mean that someone took it apart (the faults could have been temporary for instance) but it might be construed that way.

'got repaired' is passive and not very pretty, possibly consider 'needed repairing' instead.

You could rephrase the whole sentence more economically by simply saying 'we had to repair many of the appliances in our apartment', which implies they had broken down.

Please note that in most cases you ought to **prefer active phrasing** over passive phrasing. The passive tense is sometimes necessary but it's good to avoid it if you can.